# OpenCV - Function to paint text to the Canvas

Tags: python, opencv

I am detecting a face from the camera and draw a rectangle around it.
Code below:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('face_classifier.xml')

def detect(gray, frame): 
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5) 
    for (x, y, w, h) in stops: # For each detected face:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2) 
    return frame 

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True: 
    _, frame = video_capture.read() 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    canvas = detect(gray, frame) 
    cv2.imshow('Video', canvas) 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
        break
```

Are there any functions in OpenCV that can print text?
When it detects a face on the screen say "Hi"?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have done this first before asking the question but after some Googling and trying out a few things, here is the solution:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('face_classifier.xml')

def detect(gray, frame): 
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5) 
    for (x, y, w, h) in stops: # For each detected face:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2) 
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL
        cv2.putText(frame,'Hello There!',(x+w, h),font, 0.8,(255,0,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
    return frame 

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True: 
    _, frame = video_capture.read() 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    canvas = detect(gray, frame) 
    cv2.imshow('Video', canvas) 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
        break
```

This will add "Hello There!" to the top right corner of the detection frame rectangle.